Unable to add more than one character at a time when setting input state
Simple, short component, to show my problem.
'use client' component

Getting data from: dataSource
Setting the data to local state: currentDataChange
Mapping out the currentDataChange as  elements

Problem is that while I can change the input value, the mapped out component rerenders, making it so I can add only 1 character at a time before I have to click in the input and type the next one.
Previously in React, this worked fine, so I'm not sure where the problem is or how to prevent/limit the rerendering.
I have tried declaring the function separately, adding another state to hold the values, switching the mapping array and values around.
"use client";

export default function SampleComponent() {
  type DataSourceType = string[];

  const useDataSource = (): DataSourceType => {
    return ["item1", "item2", "item3"];
  };
  const dataSource = useDataSource();

  const [currentDataChange, setCurrentDataChange] = useState<DataSourceType>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (dataSource) setCurrentDataChange(dataSource);
  }, []);

  const DataMap = () => {
    if (!currentDataChange) return null;

    return currentDataChange.map((value, index) => (
      <input
        key={index}
        value={value}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setCurrentDataChange((curr) => {
            const newData = [...curr];
            newData[index] = e.target.value;
            return newData;
          });
        }}
      />
    ));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <DataMap />
    </div>
  );
}


Creating const DataMap = () => ... won't work in the same place as where I want to display the result.
How to make it work: 
Workaround 1: Create a separate component e.g., DataMap.tsx, import it and pass the setstate. 
Workaround 2: Use the array.map inline in the main return statement.

There are quite some changes to be made in your code.
Let's look at them one by one:

Initializing currentDataChange state with the value of dataSource
Adding dataSource as a dependency in useEffect
Removed the unnecessary condition for currentDataChange check inside DataMap component, as it's initialized with dataSource

This is your final edited code with all the changes:
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    
    export default function SampleComponent() {
      type DataSourceType = string[];
    
      const useDataSource = (): DataSourceType => {
        return ["item1", "item2", "item3"];
      };
      const dataSource = useDataSource();
    
      const [currentDataChange, setCurrentDataChange] = useState<DataSourceType>(
        dataSource
      );
    
      useEffect(() => {
        setCurrentDataChange(dataSource);
      }, [dataSource]);
    
      const DataMap = () => {
        if (!currentDataChange) return null;
    
        return currentDataChange.map((value, index) => (
          <input
            key={index}
            value={value}
            onChange={(e) => {
              setCurrentDataChange((curr) => {
                const newData = [...curr];
                newData[index] = e.target.value;
                return newData;
              });
            }}
          />
        ));
      };
    
      return (
        <div>
          <DataMap />
        </div>
      );
    };


Hi, thank you for the advice, good changes for cleaner code! However the problem remains, i can only add 1 character at a time, any ideas on why would that happen ?

Can you provide what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Yes, we have mapped out the X amount of input fields based on datasource (in this case 3) and set their value as such, now i would like to change their value and update the currentDataChange. e.g. currentDataChange[index] = e.target.value;. This somewhat works but the problem is that I can add only 1 character at a time, that is I type 1 character, it updates and i have to click the input element again to write another character. I would like to write in the input element without constantly needing to click in it. Hope this clears up the issue.
